# SignalR invocation lifetime outliers

Tags: signalr.client, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a .NET 7 Windows desktop application which calls methods in a localhost Windows service using SignalR. Both client and server are using version 7.0.4. In production I observe that a low percentage (<1%) of invocations take around 10x longer than all the rest. Occasionally taking more than 100ms is a major issue in this use-case.

In an attempt to narrow-down the issue, I have made a simple console app which wraps the logic of the client application and adds analysis of SignalR's logging through a custom `ILogger`. It uses a `StopWatch` to time the interval between "InvocationCreated" and the corresponding "InvocationDisposed". I have also patched the server method to simply create a return object without any useful operation. My test procedure runs 1000 operations spaced 500ms apart. Throughout multiple experiments trying out different ideas, the statistics are very consistent. >98% of invocations complete within 20ms. Most of the rest take >110ms. For example:

[image: Scatter chart of invocation lifetime of 1000 operations]

The absolute numbers are lower than the production system (due to the reduced complexity), but the distribution looks similar. **I'm looking for suggestions of things I could try to remove these outliers.** Other than removing as much of my own code from the code path as possible, the main things I've tried (without observed change) have been:

1. `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(24, 24)` on client and server.
2. `o.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)` on server.

Here's a simplified version of the SignalR client logging for one invocation:

1. Waiting on Connection Lock in InvokeCoreAsync ...
2. Invocation 1 created.
3. Preparing blocking invocation '1'...
4. Issuing Invocation '1': ...
5. Releasing Connection Lock in InvokeCoreAsyncCore ...
6. Resetting keep-alive timer, received a message from the server.
7. Received Completion for Invocation 1.
8. Invocation 1 marked as completed.
9. Invocation 1 disposed.

The sporadic latency occurs between 6 and 7. On the server side, the latency moment occurs *before* the `WebSocketsTransport` "Message received" message. That section includes JSON (de)serialization, but is not significantly affected by the size of the packet (tried 89 and 1324 bytes) or serializer (tried default JSON and `NewtonsoftJsonHubProtocol`).

Comment: I feel like it might have something to do with server load. Here is an [Azure SignalR Service performance guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-performance), maybe something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, this testing is all on a local machine using Kestrel, with no other clients, so I don't think anything in that guide applies. It *could* be affected by what other threads are doing in the same process (both client and server), but they're not doing anything heavy in this test.